# Delete Orphaned Role assignments in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cli

The role assignments where the user has been removed remain as `Identity not found`.

The `az role assignment list` does not return displayName to filter it out that way.

Ex:

```
    "canDelegate": null,
    "condition": null,
    "conditionVersion": null,
    "description": "",
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal",
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "roleDefinitionName": "User Access Administrator",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
```

Do we have any easy way of finding these and removing them using az cli? So that this can be put into a script.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have any easy way of finding these and removing them using az cli

Using azure cli I couldn't find any way to get Orphaned Roles but I could able to find an alternative that is Uinsg PowerShell as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-9.2.0)  and [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018435/what-is-the-sure-fire-way-to-find-role-assignments-with-identity-not-found-on):

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-object -Property Displayname -eq $null
```

**Output:**

[image]

You could also get Orphaned Role using below commands and I followed

```
$o = "Unknown"
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-object -Property ObjectType -eq $o
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now you can use `Remove-AzRoleAssignment` to remove these roles [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azroleassignment?view=azps-9.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used, which appears to work correctly in my use case:

```
function Remove-Orphan-Role-Assignments {
    $orphans = az role assignment list --query "[?principalName=='']" --all | ConvertFrom-Json 
    $orphanCount = $orphans.Length
    Write-Host "Orphans found: $($orphanCount)"
    if ( $orphanCount -eq 0 ) { 
        return;
    }

$reply = Read-Host -Prompt "Delete orphans? [y/n]"
if ( $reply -eq 'y' ) { 
    foreach ($orphan in $orphans)
        {
            Write-Host "roleDefinitionId: $($orphan.roleDefinitionId)"
            az role assignment delete --role $orphan.roleDefinitionId
        }
        Write-Host "$($orphanCount) deleted."
    }
}
```